# url Rewrite multiple parameters

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a page which has multiple parameters that I want to change with HTaccess

An example of the link is:
/woning.php?type=Woonhuis&adres=Groenenweer&plaats=Sliedrecht&nr=16542314

I want to change it into woning/woonhuis-Groenenweer-Sliedrecht-16542314

I've been looking and I've seen it work without the - but that makes it rather illegible
Would it be possible to make it work like this?

---

**update**

I've managed to make it work a bit using

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-([^/]+)-([^/]+)-([^/]+)-([^/]+)$ /woning.php?type=$1&status=$2&adres=$3&plaats=$4&nr=$5 [L]
```

There is a page that can be found, however, it only works if I add a dot (.) to the end but then it cannot read my parameter anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your document root:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?woning/([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)/?$ /woning.php?type=$1&adres=$2&plaats=$3&nr=$4 [L,QSA]
```

Then change all your links so that they look like: `/woning/woonhuis-Groenenweer-Sliedrecht-16542314`